# Swipe functionality over iFrame on touch devices

Tags: iframe, touch, swipe, swipe-gesture

I used the Nivo Lightbox by dev7studios on my website and I am struggling to get the touch slide/swipe functionality working over an iFrame(video).

It works perfectly directly over any image, as well as above and below the iframe content, just not directly over the iframe...

My website http://crazyway.tv/test1/videos.php.

My code atm

```
<script src="nivo-lightbox/nivo-lightbox.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){          
                jQuery('a.jig-link').nivoLightbox({effect: 'slideRight'});
                jQuery('.lightbox').nivoLightbox({effect: 'slideRight'});                   
        });
        </script>
<script src="js/jquery.touchwipe.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('body').touchwipe({
                wipeLeft: function(){ jQuery(".nivo-lightbox-next").click(); },
                wipeRight: function(){ jQuery(".nivo-lightbox-prev").click(); },
                 min_move_x: 70,
                 min_move_y: 70,                 
                 preventDefaultEvents: false                 
            });
        });     
        </script>
```